# Silverlight Custom object not inherited from Control

Tags: silverlight, templates

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to add a custom UI thingy (I don't want to call it custom control, on purpose). I want to create a custom control, but I don't really need it to be templated. I want to implement it visually using other controls. In my example, I am trying to create a control, that uses a Path object for its implementation. I wanted it to "Add" the Path control to the visual tree when it is created. I want it to expose several dependency properties, and I want it to update the Path object when the dependency properties change.

My first approach was to inherit it from Control, define a path "Part", locate it in the "OnApplyTemplate" routine, and update it when needed, but it just seems like a huge overkill. The control I implement now has the ability to get a different control template, but its completely useless because the functionality must assume a single path object in it, and it overrides most of the properties of this path. It also exposes a lot of properties that I don't need like Background, BorderBrush, BorderThickness, all of which I do not use and instead calculate from the other properties that I do expose.

So the question is, should I inherit from FrameworkElement instead, and if so, how do I "plant" the Path object that I want to use to implement my new custom control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms602714%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> It is not common to derive directly from `FrameworkElement` because certain expected services for a class that is intended for a UI representation (such as template support) are not fully implemented at that level.
>
> ...
>
> `FrameworkElement` provides support for a number of basic scenarios, but also lacks a number of features that are desirable for a "UI element" in the sense of a building block that you use to create UI in XAML. Many of these features are instead implemented on `Control`, or other immediate subclasses of `FrameworkElement`.

Decompilation of Silverlight libraries also suggests that you simply cannot 'draw' anything in a `FrameworkElement`, you need to use one if its descendants. What is possible in the WPF is not always possible in Silverlight, especially at the core level.

I would stick to a `Control` descendant. I'd apply a `TemplatePartAttribute` to the class definition to specify that it needs to have a `Path` object:

```
[TemplatePart(Name="ThePath", Type=typeof(Path))]
public class MyControl { ... }
```

Then in `OnApplyTemplate` I would check that the new template has the path. This way it would know which `Path` to use if there are more than one `Path` in the template.

This approach has one significant advantage: if someone (or even you) wants to add something to the visual appearance of the control without changing its logic, it will be done by simply defining a new template. For example, a template that wraps the `Path` with a box:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="MyControl">
  <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderThickness}"
          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderBrush}"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Control.Background}">
    <Path Name="ThePath" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Control.Foreground}"
          StrokeThickness="1.5"/>
  </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

As for exposed properties, try to use the most relevant inherited ones at least for default behavior.

Comment: Thanks Pavel, Ill go with your recommendation. The problem is that the control I am writing needs the path not to have a stroke, does not use foreground or background color, in fact requires not to be templated, so using the Control object as base class, while its probably the only way, is a huge overkill... But, as you said, there is no other way in Silverlight...

Comment: @KobiHari That's quite a strange case I should note. But maybe you'd better use another base class then. Maybe Shape? Although I've never derived from that class.

Comment: Shape seems to be the best class to derive from, except that I have no idea how to render it... In WPF I would extend Geometry, and then Extend Shape and use my new geometry but this is all impossible in Silverlight. Its possible to inherit from other base classes, but I don't know how to modify the visual tree once I do that... Starting to think that it may not be possible at all.

Comment: @KobiHari Ahh, no way. Seems like all `Shape`s are implemented in native code. For example, the only thing `Path` class has is a 'Core' dependency property `Data` with code `10533U`. This means it's simply a managed wrapper over a native implementation. Sorry, this won't work.